# Meteor passing MongoDB selector from parameter

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to so some query that is as same as `LIKE` from the good old school rdbms, so I have to use some sort of regex for that.

When I try this, it works fine

```
Countdowns.find({"name":{ "$regex": /ANW/ }},{ sort: {regDate: -1 }});
```

the value returns correctly. However when I build the mongoDb selector (the first JSON param for the function) it never works.

```
var key = Session.get('searchKey');
var field = Session.get('searchField');
var temp = '{"'+ field +'":{ "$regex": /'+key+'/ }}';

var selector = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp));
Countdowns.find(selector,{ sort: {regDate: -1 }});
```

When i test it out (using try-catch during JSON.parse), the JSON object was built without any error but somehow the function (`find()`) fails to operate when i pass it as variable.

Is there other way to build the selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested on the console and this is what I got.

[image: The selector is a string, you need a RegExp]

Try to make it this way

```
  var key = Session.get('key'), field = Session.get('field');
  var selector = {}; 
      selector[field] = { $regex : new RegExp(key) };
```

With this you will get:

[image: With new RegExp('string')]

And that should be acceptable for minimongo.

---

Why `JSON.parse` didn't work? At the point you where passing `temp` this is what it looked like:

[image: string of a string]

You already had a string before passing it to `JSON.stringify`. But wait! You would say, if I instead pass it to `JSON.parse` it will work? Let see:

[image: the forward slash is not well formatted]

Nope. The forward slash has to be properly formatted and even then you'll get a string for the `$regex`, and you want a [`RegExp` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

[image: even if formatted you get a string that looks like a RegExp]

So the way one end ups doing this is what I wrote you before. First you define the variable that will hold your selector for the database as an object and with that you construct your `selector`.

Comment: Works! I don't understand..why `JSON.parse` did not generate JSON object? From the documentation, it should generate a JSON object from the string.